# how to make text transparent without changing to an image using css

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar that tells the user which page is selected by a change in text colour and a black background. I want to make only the text inside the current page nav transparent.

Example here: [sammarchant.co.uk/new](http://sammarchant.co.uk/new/) - scroll down to grey area to view

I have researched using CSS3 but no luck, I want to keep load times down to the very minimum hence not wanting to use an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with plain CSS/CSS3.

Even if you did make the text transparent, it wouldn't appear grey when scrolling over the grey area. If the text was transparent, it would show the black background behind it.

You could however use some javascript to detect what the background is, and change the color of the font depending on this.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to match the square logo on the left so that the rest of the design shows through when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be something like this :-

```
nav a.current {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

EDIT: As per your comment adding this

```
CSS:
nav a.current span {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

HTML:
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><span>Link></span><a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: but this changes the background opacity also, I just want to target the text.

Comment: you can apply a simple trick by wrapping the text in a `<span>` and then decrease the opacity for the same. for example like this `<a href="#"><span></span></a>` so the new css selecter would be `nav a.current span {  }`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in pure CSS, without using images is to use a custom font. All you have to do is find/create a font, in which the characters are transparent letters with black background. Similar to [this font](http://www.dafont.com/impact-label.font?nb_ppp=50&af=on)

You can place an appropriate font on your server and import it using  [CSS @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face) rule

Comment: Yes I had that idea myself last night although I would need the Nevis font glyphs and then edit them in Font software, and these wont be easy to find.

Comment: @SamMarchant now that I think of it, adding a custom font would be as bad for load times as images. I'm afraid images are the best solution here after all. Just reduce their size by keeping the color space as small as possible. Another option is to experiment with SVG. However, the file size reduction is most visible for simple, large images. These are really small so the code can as well turn out to take as much space as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

you used white color as text color and black as background
so if its trnaparent its look like grey

your Code look something like this

```
css
    nav a.current {
        background:black;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* For IE*/
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);  
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;    
        opacity: 0.5;
    }


Html

    <nav>
         <a class="current" href="index.html">home</a>             
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `fontsize:0px`.You will get the text as transparent.